# HAProxy 1.6 redirect using http-response, map and regsub

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I want to setup a redirect map similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001799/how-do-i-used-the-map-feature-in-haproxy-to-build-massive-redirect-tables-1-5

The difference is I want to use `http-response` instead of `http-request`. The reason being is because I want to redirect **only** when backend server returns 404.

This is my config

```
http-response redirect location %[capture.req.uri,regsub(\?(.*),),map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] code 301 if { status 404 } { capture.req.uri,regsub(\?(.*),),map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found }
```

I tried to use `regsub` to remove query params from `capture.req.uri`. But, I get this error when restarting HAProxy.

`[ALERT] 280/171612 (6176) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:87] : error detected in proxy 'http' while parsing 'http-response redirect' rule : error in condition: invalid arg 2 in conv method 'regsub' : missing arguments (got 1/2), type 'string' expected in ACL expression 'capture.req.uri,regsub(\?(.*),),map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)'.
[ALERT] 280/171612 (6176) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
Errors found in configuration file, check it with 'haproxy check'.`

Is there a way to get the URL without query params ? I tried to use `path` instead of `capture.req.uri` but HAProxy won't start.

This is my config using `path`

`http-response redirect location %[path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] code 303 if { status 404 } { path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found }`

And this is the warning

`[WARNING] 283/090721 (2875) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:88] : 'redirect' : sample fetch <path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)> may not be reliably used here because it needs 'HTTP request headers' which is not available here.
[WARNING] 283/090721 (2875) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:88] : anonymous acl will never match because it uses keyword 'path' which is incompatible with 'backend http-response header rule'`

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that because of a parser limitation, `regsub` doesn't support capture groups, and `regsub(\?(.*),)` doesn't make sense here anyway -- you're capturing something you aren't using.  Perhaps simply `regsub(\?.*,)` is what you are looking for?  But `path` should have worked as well and would probably be better, so you might want to show the error there.

Comment: hi Michael, you are correct, `regsub` doesn't support capture groups. I've updated the answer with the error if I am trying to use `path`

Comment: Sorry, I completely overlooked the fact that you were using `http-response`.  Using `http-response` causes actions to occur after HAProxy has selected a backend, sent a request to it, received a response, and is ready to process it (which is why path isn't available -- that buffer has been released).  This is allowed in a front end for purposes of logical organization but doesn't make sense here. You should be using `http-request redirect ...` -- you are processing the client's request, not the server's response (there is no server involved here -- HAProxy generates the redirects internally).

Comment: hi @Michael-sqlbot, the reason I am using `http-response` is because I *only* want to redirect if the backend returns 404. That's why I have `status 404` in one of the conditions. I tried to create a header of the current path using `http-request set-header X-Path-Something %[path]` but I don't the header get sent back to HAProxy.

Comment: Wow... I can't read today. Okay, so, first, use `http-request set-var(txn.path) path` to preserve the path in a transaction variable so it is available during response processing if needed.  Then fetch and use it with `http-response redirect location %[var(txn.path),map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] code 303 if { status 404 } { var(txn.path),map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found }`

Comment: hi @Michael-sqlbot, thanks for the help, it works really well. If you want, you can add your solution as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original issue was a problem with `regsub(\?(.*),)`, which caused a problem because the the `regsub` converter  is limited to expressions the configuration parser can handle -- and parentheses aren't usable because the parser sees the `)` as closing `regsub()` with too few arguments.  (For literals, you can use `\\xnn` hex-escapes to work around parser limitations, but that wouldn't work here.)

`regsub` was being used because this redirect is being triggered during response processing `if { status 404 }`, and the `path` fetch is not available by that stage of processing -- HAProxy frees the buffers used to by the request once it is sent to a server.

However, HAProxy 1.6 also introduces user variables that can be used to carry data across from the request side if used in transaction (`txn`) scope.

During request processing, stash the contents of the `path` fetch in a transaction-scoped variable called (coincidentally) `path`.

```
http-request set-var(txn.path) path
```

Then, it can be accessed during response processing.

The following is shown on multiple lines for clarity but must be on a single line of configuration.

```
http-response redirect 
    location %[var(txn.path),map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] 
    code 303 
    if { status 404 } { var(txn.path),map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found }
```

This -- if the response status code is 404 -- fetches the value back out of the variable and checks to see if it has a value in the map file.  If so, that value is used for the redirect.